# how to write a simple ng-show directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble with the simple basics of angular directives and I was hoping for the most basic example of how to write an new ng-show directive. ie. I want to write directive ng-show2 to work the same as ng-show.

I get confused because in the angular.js file, the directive is defined like this:

```
var ngShowDirective = ngDirective(function(scope, element, attr){
  scope.$watch(attr.ngShow, function(value){
    element.css('display', toBoolean(value) ? '' : 'none');
  });
});
```

but then most of the directive examples I see are written like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('ngShow2', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(){....}
});
```

​
what exactly is corresponding with what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert on AngularJS internals, but what you are seeing[1] is a method angular uses to create directives internally. If you look at the `ngDirective`'s  signature you'll notice is the same as the `link` function used in most examples.

During the built process the function `ngShowDirective` is added to the `ng` module. [2], and AFIK is not exposed.

Since what you want is a basic example of how to implement a `ng-show` directive, all you need to do is create a module for your app, and add the directive to that module, here's a simple example

```
App.directive('ngShow2', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            scope.$watch(attr.ngShow2, function(value){
               element.css('display', value ? '' : 'none');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/L7QEE/

---

[1] https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L36-40

[2] https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/AngularPublic.js#L89

Answer (score 1):

This code works as well

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h1 ng-show2="show" ng-bind="name"></h1>
</body>
</html>​

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl($scope){
    $scope.name = 'Guest';
    $scope.show = true;
  });

  app.directive('ngShow2', function(){
    return function($scope, $element, $attributes){
      var expr = $attributes.ngShow2;
      $element.css('display', $scope[expr] ? '' : 'none');
    };
  });
</script>
```